# Netsuite Client Script Add New Item Issue

Tags: javascript, loops, netsuite

I am trying to add a new sales item on the prepare estimates page at the bottom under items tab in Netsuite. I wrote a client side script that takes a list of item ids and commits them to a new line. This code sits inside a loop and works perfectly on windows. When used on any ios device, only one item gets added replacing every item that was in the array, committing only the last. Ive tried using 'selectNewline' and 'insertLine" methods to fix this but with no luck.

Ive tried 'selectNewLine' and 'insertLine' methods. I also treid using a forEach method instead of a for loop.

for (var i = 0;i < itemMod.length; i++){

```
                currentRecord.insertLine({
                  sublistId: 'item',
                  line: i // Use the loop index as the line number
                });

               

                // Set the values for the new line
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'item',
                value: itemMod[i].id // -1 represents the transactional item, modify if needed
                });



                // Set other desired field values for the new line
                currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'quantity',
                value: itemMod[i].count
                });

                // Commit the new line
                currentRecord.commitLine({
                sublistId: 'item'
                });



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in dynamic mode, you need to use

```
objRecord.selectNewLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
});  

objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'item',
    value: {{your value}},
    ignoreFieldChange: false // Trigger action if needed
});
//... More code

objRecord.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
});
```

Use this if you want to add new lines.

But if you want to modify already existing lines, you need to use

```
objRecord.selectLine({
    sublistId: 'item',
    line: i
});
```

Instead of selectNewLine

Comment: I beleive I am in dynamic mode because no line items exist prior to hitting the submit button, I am not editing already existing line items. So I used your first solution but I am still getting the same result

Comment: currentRecord.selectNewLine({
                      sublistId: 'item'
                    }); 

    
                    // Set the values for the new line
                    currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'item',
                    value: itemMod[i].id,
                    ignoreFieldChange: false
       
                    });

Comment: Can you give your trigger point?